# how i can correct this error in ruby installed ruby is 1.9.3 and it shows the path of installed ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, redmine

what is that probem and how can i solve it

```
RubyGems Environment:
   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
   - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-15 patchlevel 429) [x86_64-linux]
   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
   - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin
   - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
   - ruby
   - x86_64-linux
   - GEM PATHS:
   - /home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
   - /home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648:/home8/novapext/.rvm/gems   /ruby-2.0.0-p648@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
 - "gemhome" => "/home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648"
 - "gempath" => "/home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648:/home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global"
 - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/
```

this is therubygem environment how i can correct this it showing the ruby version 1.9.3 and installation directory is /home8/novapext/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648 this is my error

Comment: @M Junaid Aslam: you are saying you want ruby version of 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

You could switch your rvm environment to ruby 1.9.3

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3
```